# Is there any way to remove "next payment date" from a subscription email?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

My client wants to remove "**the next payment date**" from woocommerce email.

I`ve been looking for hours for a solution but i didnt`t find one. Is there any way to manipulate that data?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. Include a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The basic subscription flow is that you can set your next subscription date like this -

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'update_skip_next_payment_date', 20, 1);

function update_skip_next_payment_date($subscription) {
 $date = new DateTime('2024-11-21');
 $date->setTime(11, 59);

 $subscription_next_payment_date = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); // = '2021-05-28 08:55:00'

  $new_dates = array(
    'start' => $subscription->get_date('start'),
    'trial_end' => $subscription->get_date('trial_end'),
    'next_payment' => $subscription_next_payment_date,
    'last_payment' => $subscription->get_date('last_payment'),
    'end' => $subscription->get_date('end'),
  );

   $subscription->update_dates($new_dates);
}
```

So you can update the next subscription date here and set it next to the next subscription date here.

The reference URL is - [How to set Next Payment date in Woocommerce Subscriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068851/how-to-set-next-payment-date-in-woocommerce-subscriptions)

The woocommerce subscription reference URL is - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/#section-4):

Comment: I don`t want to set it....  i want to remove it from the email that customer gets.