# Woocommerce subscriptions manual renewal

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have read this thread
[How to set Next Payment date in Woocommerce Subscriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068851/how-to-set-next-payment-date-in-woocommerce-subscriptions)

Where A function to set a different billing date for a subscription was shown:

```
function update_next_payment_date($subscription) {
    $date = new DateTime('2021-05-28');
    $date->setTime(8, 55);

    $subscription_next_payment_date = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); // = '2021-05-28 08:55:00'

    $new_dates = array(
        'start' => $subscription->get_date('start'),
        'trial_end' => $subscription->get_date('trial_end'),
        'next_payment' => $subscription_next_payment_date,
        'last_payment' => $subscription->get_date('last_payment'),
        'end' => $subscription->get_date('end'),
    );

    $subscription->update_dates($new_dates);
}
```

I was wondering where should I put the code to force an existing subscription to execute a transaction instead of waiting passivly for the transaction to execute,

I saw somewhere that you should put it in the functions.php file or declare it there and upload it to the themes folder,

What am I missing?
How do I force a subscription renewal ?

I tried declaring the function in functions.php with an uploaded file to THEMES.

I expected a renewal.